# OAuth 2.0 - why consent screen doesn't require client secret?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I'm learning OAuth 2.0. When using authorization code flow, it's enough to pass client ID. Does it mean that, in theory, an attacker can generate multiple authorization codes easily?

What was the reason why the consent screen  doesn't use client secret? It's secure, as authorization server should deliver HTTPS connection.

Is it only for simplicity, to allow linking on client-side, like this?

```
<a href="https://koala-auth.com/authorize?client_id=abc123">Login with Koala Auth</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, according to [RFC-6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1) section 1.3.1, the user is authenticated by the Authorization Server before an authorization code is given back. Therefore, the client ID is not the only piece of data the is needed to get an authorization code.

This is not because the resource owner redirects the user-agent to the authorization server that this authorization server will give back an authorization code: the user-agent must complete an authentication step with a valid user, before the authorization code is given back to the resource owner.

Comment: Hmm, I’m not sure if I understand. In Laravel framework, it’s enough to pass client ID to generate consent screen, but of course you need to pass the secret along with the code to get the access token. What other „piece of information” do you mean?

Comment: Passing the client ID is not sufficient to generate an authorization code: the Laravel framework does not give any other piece of information, but it does not get back the code if there is no user-agent to authenticate using a login/password or other type of crendentials. Laravel gives the client ID, the user-agent gives some user's credentials and with those two types of informations, Laravel gets back a code. Just try to get a code with Laravel but do not authenticate the user-agent, you will not get back any code. See fig. 3 (Authorization Code Flow) in RFC-6749.

Comment: Fig. 3 in RFC-6749: step B is between step A (Client Identifier redirection)  and step C (Authorization Code sent). Step B gives another piece of data: "User authenticates".

Comment: I made a small test in Laravel. I logged in on oauth server as user #1 and had a client assigned to user #2. Then, I requested authorization code passing just client ID. It worked fine. Then, I exchanged the code to access token, still being logged in on oauth server as user #1. It worked fine as well. Is it bad implementation of OAuth 2.0 from Laravel? It's quite weird that code authorization routes (both steps) require being logged in, but you can be logged in as a user who is not an owner of the client app.

Comment: Depends on many things: those two users were using the same browser sharing session cookies? (even with different windows, some browsers share the session cookies) I do not know if Laravel has security flaws, but the whole community that analyzed Oauth2 has not found any flaw until now. So the protocol is correct, until somebody finds some vulnerability, of course.

Comment: The protocol doesn't have flaws itself, but most implementations do, from what I've heard. OAuth 2.0 is messy. I have `client.test` domain and `server.test` domain. I logged in as user 1 on `server.test` and requested access token to `client_id`, which is assigned to user 2. Entire flow was successful, which is weird. My only idea is that maybe client secret is encoded and contains user ID? I doubt it though. I'm now going to create another client, but create it for user 2 instead of updating existing client to `user_id=2`. Will let you know how it went.

Comment: Yeah, it worked just fine as well. I thought that OAuth 2.0 authorization doesn't require being logged in, but it indeed does. Why Laravel's implementation ignores the owner of the client though, is a mystery.

Comment: Could you please validate the answer if it corresponds to what you were waiting for? Thanks!